# Struct members ordering advantages in C

Tags: c, optimization, struct

I know that in C, the order of the struct members is the order in which they are declared plus (usually , unless stated otherwise) padding might occur , leading to the two first structs I created with their respective size:

```
struct MyStructV1
{
    int a;
    char c;
    int b;  
};

printf("size of MyStructV1 is:%lu \n",sizeof(struct MyStructV1)); // prints 12

struct MyStructV1Packed
{
    int a;
    char c;
    int b;
}__attribute__((__packed__));;

printf("size of MyStructV1Packed is:%lu \n",sizeof(struct MyStructV1Packed)); // prints 9
```

So far so good.

My question is, then, does the following declaration of "the unpacked" version of MyStructV2 has any benefits/advantages over the first version of MyStructV1 ?

```
struct MyStructV2
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

printf("size of MyStructV2 is:%lu \n",sizeof(struct MyStructV2)); // prints 12 as well
```

Note that now the order of the members has changes (b is declared before c).

I'm referring to memory access "costs" or cycles needs to be done in order to read/write the struct members and/or any other considerations that are relevant ?

Is it compiler/architecture dependent (if at all) ?

Cheers,

Guy.

Comment: Most of the time it does not matter at all. You might want to put wider fields before shorter ones. Of course it depends upon the architecture and the ABI

Comment: It is very compiler dependent. A very good rule-of-thumb to go along with that is don't worry about packing structs unless you have some architecture and compiler specific reason for doing so and know exactly what that is. Otherwise, you are far better off letting the compiler handle it and insert a byte or two of padding as it sees fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be little or no difference between the first and last versions. In both structs, the `int` members are aligned on word boundaries, so they can be read from memory efficiently. The only difference between them is that the padding is between `c` and `b` in `MyStructV1`, and at the end of the structure in `MyStructV2`. But there is no execution overhead due to padding; accessing struct members is done simply by adding a known offset to the address of the beginning of the struct. In `MyStructV1` the offset of `b` is `8`, in `MyStructV2` it's `4`.

Comment: It is not 100% the truth. Especially if we consider structure packing. Packing on many platforms involves the byte access, and it can even stop program from working. Example: peripheral required word or halfword access but the structure is packed and it is byte accessed. Packing is overused by the beginners, and should be used with care

Comment: @PeterJ_01 The question was about comparing the two structures that *don't* use packing. You're correct that packing can produce performance hits.

Answer (score 1):

If char is smaller then int (usually it is so), the structure MyStructV1 CAN be smaller than MyStructV2.

Depending on the environment (architecture and compiler options) struct MyStructV1 can envelop a pad or can misalign b.
Depending on the architecture, if b is misaligned loading it can require more cpu clocks.

Moreover, depending on the architecture, reading a can load something more to be immediately available, if there are paddings this benefit is reduced or lost.

Comment: Very very poor and imprecise answer. IMO you should delete it

Comment: IMHO it is a short correct answer and I hope it is useful to someone.
Anyway if you have a different opinion please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

That is more interesting and of course ordering matters.

```
struct aaa1{
    char a;
    char a1;
    int b;
};

struct aaa2{
    char a;
    char a1;
    char a2;
    int b;
};

struct aaa3{
    char a;
    char a1;
    char a2;
    char a3;
    int b;
};

struct aaa4{
    char a1;
    char a2;
    char a3;
    int b;
    char a;
};

int main(void) {

struct aaa5{
    char a;
    int b;
    char a1;
};


    printf("%zu %zu %zu %zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof(struct aaa), sizeof(struct aaa1), sizeof(struct aaa2), sizeof(struct aaa3), sizeof(struct aaa4), sizeof(struct aaa5));
```

Output : 8 8 8 8 12 12